# DbSets are NULL for mocked Database using MOQ framework

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to get started on using unit tests. For this I'm using MOQ
I have the following code:

UnitTestProject:

```
        public void GetUsers_Test()
        {
            var mockDb = new Mock<IContext>();
            var fakeDbSet = new MockDbSet<User>();
            fakeDbSet.AddRange(new List<User>() {
               new User() { Id = 1, Name = "Gustavo", RoleId = 1 },
               new User() { Id = 2, Name = "Peter-Jan", RoleId = 2  }
            });

            mockDb.Setup(s => s.Set<User>()).Returns(fakeDbSet);

            UserRepository userRep = new UserRepository(mockDb.Object);

            var users = userRep.GetUsers(1);
            Assert.AreEqual(users.Count(), 2);
        }
```

Repository:

```
    public class UserRepository : BaseRepository, IUserRepository
    {
        public UserRepository(IContext context) : base(context) { }
        public List<User> GetUsers(int roleId)
        {
             if (roleId != 1)
             {
                 throw new UserRepoExceptions.NoRightsForRole();
             }
             return Dbc.Users.Select(s => new User(s)).ToList();
        }
     }
```

Even though I am creating a fakeDbSet, adding some users to it and specifying that this is what should be returned when using the User DbSet via MOQ's Setup method, Dbc.Users is still NULL.

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Don't use Moq on DbSet. DbSet is *not* used independently either, it's used through a DbContext - unless you use the "generic" repository *anti*pattern. Create a DbContext backed by the [In-Memory provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory) instead

Comment: A DbSet *is* a repository, a DbContext *is* a Unit-of-Work. It looks like you created a low-level repository (a CRUD-style DAO actually) and put it on top of a high-level ORM, introducing an IContext interface that doesn't really exist. What's the point? You end up testing your scaffolding, not the application code or data operations

Comment: What you mock is `Set<User>()`. But then you ask for `Users`. Mocked context is not that smart to realize the two are the same. You need to separately mock `Users` too.